# maintain state of uiviewcontroller during navigation using storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, state

in any iPhone app, consider the following sequence (VC=ViewController) :

1. VC-A is displayed ... user hits a button to load VC-B
2. VC-B is now pushed and displayed ... user moves a slider from 0 to 5 ... then hits Back on navBar
3. VC-B is popped, VC-A is displayed ... user hits a button again to load VC-B
4. VC-B is pushed and displayed ... but the slider is back to 0

This is happening because VC-B instance in step 2 above is different than VC-B instance in step 4, hence the state is lost. To avoid this, I can either make VC-B a singelton, or keep a strong reference to VC-B somewhere and reuse it instead of creating a new instance.

This logic used to work well when I was loading my VCs from a nib, since I would create the instance of the VC manually inside the code. With storyboards, this doesnt work, since it is the segue that creates the instance automatically. How can I then ensure that I reuse my VCs instead?

I tried the following trick to maintain a singelton:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(instance==nil){
        NSLog(@"LMHomeViewController init called");
        instance = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        super.screenType = [NSNumber numberWithInt:home_screen];
    }
    return instance;
}
```

but I got a runtime error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'
```

Any suggestions here? My interest is to maintain the state of the VC as the user goes back and forth in the navigation tree.

Note: the *state* in my case is a UIWebView, hence its not possible to persist its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a case for using `NSUserDefaults` - read state in on `viewWillAppear`, write it out on `viewWillDisappear`, (and wherever else appropriate)

In any case, it's better MVC to persist in your model rather than in the view hierarchy. So if not NSUserDefaults, consider a singleton that only needs to store the state data.

Another idea. if you *do* want to keep the viewController object around - don't use a storyboard segue. Keep a strong reference in a property and use

```
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.persistingViewController];
```

The `persistingViewController` accessor can lazily-instantiate the viewController first time round. So long as you keep the reference, you can reuse:

```
  - (UIViewController*) persistingViewController
  {
     if (!_persistingViewController) {
       UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
     _persistingViewController = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];

   }

   return self.persistingViewController
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot. The proposed solution doesnt use Segues though ... the real charm for using Storyboards. Is it then fair to say that the Storyboard concept was designed to provide an IoC type situation, whereby the programmer is discouraged to create VC objects manually. It really should have been easy to override the init method to allow singeltons etc ... anyways, I am leaving the question open for discussion. Thanks again for your kind comments.